# Determining which certificate to use in two way ssl

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https

I'm having an issue sending our certificate (client) to another server during a web service call.

We're expected to return the certificate with the CN:

```
b2b-test
```

however whenever we receive the servers certificate and attempt to send our own, we're getting:

```
Unable to find valid certificate path to requested target
```

From my understanding, if I put our certificate b2b-test inside of our keystore jre/lib/security/cacerts, then when receiving the server request, it should send the appropriate certificate.

How does the client know which key from the keystore it should send to the server?  Should I be specifying the exact certificate to send during my request, or is it enough for it to be in the keystore?

Currently the server is sending back the certificate

```
b2b-a
```

The certificate chain shows:

```
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=b2b-a, OU=Web Technologies
```

The URL for the service is:

```
https://b2b-a/service
```

If I configure it like one way ssl, and put the servers certificate into our cacerts, then it picks up their cert and fails the handshake (I'm assuming because it's expecting our cert and not theirs back due to it being a two way setup).

I'm a little stumped here.  Any clarification on what I've said is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Unable to find valid certificate path to requested target" error usually occurs when one side passes a certificate for which the other side doesn't trust any of the certs in the chain.  You'll generally (always?) see the error message on the side that's receiving the cert (the side that's missing the truststore).

If you're the client and they're the server, one-way SSL would send their cert from them to you and you would validate it (making sure that the hostname matches the content in the cert), but it would not send any cert from you to them nor would they do any validation.

You'll want to make sure you're configuring a truststore that contains either the b2b-a certificate or a certificate that was used to sign it (but that cert doesn't appear to have any root CAs, so you're stuck with directly importing the cert itself).  So yes, you want to do what you wrote in your post and put their certificate into your cacerts.  And you'll also need to make sure that the b2b-a service trusts the cert you're sending (or a root CA that was used to sign your cert, if any), so you'll need to put your cert into their cacerts as well, or do something equivalent.

Note that putting a cert in cacerts (or in a truststore JKS) *DOES NOT* send any certs to anyone; any truststore is used *only* to allow you to validate that you trust the certificate someone else provides you, either because you trust the cert or because you trust a CA cert that was used to sign the cert.  No certs are picked out of the cacerts directory to send to another machine.

If you're using a JKS rather than the JRE directory (which is generally a better idea, since you can specify a different set of trusted certs for your process without changing the default set for anyone running a Java project within your JRE), it's possible to use the same JKS as both a keystore and a truststore (you'll just provide the same filename and password for both the keystore and the truststore properties), or you can have two separate files; either approach will work.

Answer (score 2):

> From my understanding, if I put our certificate b2b-test inside of our keystore jre/lib/security/cacerts, then when receiving the server request, it should send the appropriate certificate.

Certainly not. That's a truststore. A source of trusted certificates. Don't mess with it. It isn't used for the purpose you require and in any case it is updated every Java dot release, which clobbers your changes.

Your own certificate and private/public key pair should go in a file of your own, a *keystore*, which is defined to JSSE by the `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` and `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword` system properties, or by more complex means described in the JSSE Reference Guide.

The keystore is a precious and confidential file containing your private key. Guard and protect it. Private key leakage would compromise your security and identity.